# Playing low cards in position

Tags: texas-hold-em

Hello I am wondering if it's worth while to play hands like 3h 6d in position, when nobody has raised? I would certainly fold to any pre-flop raises, but what about when nobody raises? 
Thanks!

Andy.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes and no, because it depends on your position.

If you are in early position, then the answer is a definite **NO**. There are many players left to act behind you, you're OOP and most of the time, they'll call you or reraise you with better hands.

In late position, sometimes the answer is yes. When? When you steal the blinds. From my experience, you can steal with trash hands, but a few conditions must be met:

1. you must be in CO or BTN;
2. the blinds must fold very often to blind steals;
3. the BTN must fold often as well, if you're in CO.

If these conditions are met, go ahead and raise.

One last word: don't expect to make big money in these spots with trash hands like the one you mentioned. It is enough for one of the other chaps to defend, for your profits to be dwindled a little.

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote it and mark is as accepted if you think it was helpful, so other people are guided easier in the future

Answer (score 2):

Open 63o? Definitely not! Not from any position. It is that simple. Especially in enviroments where the rake is high this is a hugely losing play. I agree with Doicin when the blinds don't defend enough you should widen up your range, but to play 63o the blinds should be folding an absurd amount of hands. When you are in late position and the blinds are too tight consider opening 65s, 96s, but not 63o.

Comment: When the rake is high enough even AA become a losing play.

Comment: How does this comment add anything useful? What you say is really unrealistic. Even if there was no rake opening 63o is a losing play the fast majority of the time.

Comment: It's true. I meant that rake decreases the win rate for all the cards, not only trash so, in my opinion, it is not a factor. Maybe I had expressed myself wrongly.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin Fair point, except for some hands that are right around break even. Then rake can be decisive. But you are right.